# Will an interface-implementing form free itself when there are no more references to it?

Tags: delphi, interface, tform

If I implement an interface on a form such as `TMyForm = class(TForm, IMyInterface)`, will the object free itself when there are no more interface references to it? It seems not to, although I couldn't work out how TForm is reference counted (if at all). I'm concerned about the form getting freed when an interface reference goes out of scope, but this does not seem to happen.

I guess there are two parts to the question, firstly whether a form might get unexpectedly freed (the real question), and secondly how forms are reference counted.

Comment: @TLama TForm descends from TComponent, which implements IInterface and IInterfaceComponentReference.  TComponent does implement the _AddRef and _Release, but they seem to only conditionally do reference counting.

Comment: @Alister: `TComponent` disables reference counting on itself, but will perform reference counting on its `VCLCOMObject` property, if assigned.

Comment: @Alister, sorry, maybe I misunderstood your question (before re-reading it a few times), but I thought you were asking what happens if you add an interface (to be implemented in the `TForm` class). If adding of that interface is dangerous somehow, and if that adds a reference counting to the form.

Comment: @TLama: adding an interface to a `TForm` will not add a reference count to the `TForm`. The compiler will still call `_AddRef()` and `_Release()` on interace pointers but they will be no-ops because of `TComponent`.

Comment: It's not that simple, @Free. See what everyone else has written here. In particular, Remy's comment right before yours, Uwe's answer, and the places in the question reporting that it didn't work that way.

Comment: *slap forehead* yes, sure, I forgot about what!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`TForm` derives from `TComponent`, which implements `_AddRef()` and `_Release()` to disable reference counting on itself.  As such, any interface implemented by any `TComponent` descendant class, like `TForm`, will not free its implementing `TComponent` object by default when the interface is released.

However, if an `IVCLComObject` interface is assigned to the `TComponent.VCLCOMObject` property, then `TComponent` will delegate reference counting to that object, so that object can be freed if its reference count falls to 0 (`TComponent` does not increment the reference count of its `IVCLCOMObject` reference).

This is valid for all descendants of `TComponent`, unless they implement any reference counting of their own by overriding `_AddRef()` and `_Release()` manually.

Comment: I'm more concerned as to what else might set the VCLComObject.

Comment: @Alister: `TComponent.VCLCOMObject` is set if `TComponent.ComObject` is accessed, which is only valid if the project is using the `VCLCom` unit (otherwise accessing the `ComObject` property will raise an exception).

Comment: In other words: as long as you don't expose your form somehow through a COM server, where reference counting seems adequate, there is little chance that something will set VCLComObject without your own intervention.

Answer (score 0):

IF you implement an interface in a form, it can be worth adding your own

```
_Release as follows:

    function _Release: Integer; stdcall;

function TMyInterfacedForm._Release: Integer;
begin
  result:=-1; 
end;
```

I found that it was possible to free a form with an interface, and then have the _Release called as the local variable went out of scope. This could produce an access violation, as the Tcomponent implementation checks to see if FVCLComObject is set

```
  if FVCLComObject = nil then
    Result := -1   // -1 indicates no reference counting is taking place
  else
    Result := IVCLComObject(FVCLComObject)._Release;
```

Since at this stage, FVCLComobject is undefined, an annoying A/V exception can occur.
By hardwiring the -1, it can be called safely without trigger exceptions.