# Do I need to implement IInterface methods when I create a Delphi TForm that uses an interface

Tags: delphi

I am implementing a solution where I want my Delphi form to implement an interface. Normally, I would use TInterfacedObject but this a TForm. I implemented this without any regard to reference counting. And I did not see memory leaks reported.

`TForm = class(TForm, ISomething)`

But it seems if I don't inherit from TInterfacedObject, I should be implementing the three methods required.

Am I missing something?

Comment: You're not forced to implement reference counting methods. Take your `ISomething` interface implementation just as adding the interface methods into the class (your class will have to declare them).

Comment: It depends on what model of lifetime management you want to use. So, can you tell us that?

Comment: Those methods are already implemented in TComponent and therefore in TForm, too. So you don't need to implement them. But it seems that you are actually asking about having reference counted TForm class?

Comment: Related, [Will an interface-implementing form free itself when there are no more references to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20386734/576719)